# Simple VueJS Hello world application is not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am a fully beginner in VueJS and this is my first application. It is a Hello world app, but the code is not working ;(
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learning VueJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{ title }}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.0/vue.cjs.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'Hello world!'.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` must be a function.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data()
      return {
          title: 'Hello world!',
      };
    }
});
```

See docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CDN link that uses Vue 3 version with a code syntax that runs in Vue 2, since you're beginner you should change the CDN link to vue 2 :

```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
```

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello world!'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ title }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree, though notably Vue 3 is committed to supporting this syntax. See the Vue 3 docs here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html (except maybe the `new Vue(` part, which I haven't tried)

Comment: There's no `new Vue` in vue 3 you should use `const app = Vue.createApp({})` to create new instance

Comment: Ok yeah, OP this is two problems but it looks like you want Vue 2 here

Comment: the OP has one problem which is the CDN link, the data `data:{...}` syntax could work with  vue 2 when using vue via CDN

Comment: No, data should be a function in either version. See Vue 2 docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function